# Unzip File More than 3GB on 32Bit Android

Tags: android, unzip

Is it possible to unzip large file (in this case more than 3GB) in android 32Bit Processor? I have try running on 64Bit Processor and I unzip successfully. But when I try run on 32 Bit Processor it always got error. How can I unzip this file on 32Bit Processor?

Comment: A 32-bit processor should not prevent you from unzipping any size of zip file. The program you are using to unzip is more likely to be an issue. There is a limit of 4Gig for unzip, unless the zip file has been created with the Zip64 extension AND the unzip you are using also supports Zip64. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error reading data for **** near offset 60943215, it happen when I run on Device 32Bit Processor, but the unzip process is success when I run on Device with 64Bit Processor

Comment: What exactly are you using to do the unzip on both setups? Also, what filesystems are being used on the 32-bit setup and the 64-bit setup?